# (Durrett , Probability : Theory and Examples ) Brownian Motion Reflection Principle

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

This is from excercise 7.4.3.

For $u<v\leq a$ , the following holds.
\begin{equation}
P_0 (T_a<t,u<B_t<v) = P_0 (2a-v<B_t<2a-u)
\end{equation}

Letting $(u,v)$ shrink down to $x$, for $a<x$
$$P_0 (T_a<t, B_t = x) = p_t (0,2a-x)$$

I know this should hold intuitively, but is there more rigourous proof of this?

I guess it is due to continuity of Brownian motion, but can't think of formal proof.

Comment: Consider switching direction after $T_a$, i.e., $X_t=B_t$ for $t\leq T_a$ and $X_t=2a-B_t$ for $t>T_a$.  Show that $X$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: What does $X_t$ have to do with $P_0(T_a<t,B_t=x)$ or $p_t(0,2a-x)$?

Answer (score 1):

It's due to the continuity of $y\mapsto p_t(0,y)$:
$$
\lim_{u\uparrow x,v\downarrow x}{P_0(2a-v<B_t<2a-u)\over v-u}=\lim_{u\uparrow x,v\downarrow x}\int_{2a-v}^{2a-u}{p_t(0,y) dy\over v-u}=p_t(0,2a-x).
$$